# COUNT returns total rows ignoring LIMIT in MySQL, why?

Tags: mysql, count, limit, sql-limit

Today while I was writing a complex query, accidently I found that even I have set `LIMIT` in my query MySQL server returns the total number of rows for `COUNT`.

---

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `log` LIMIT 10;
```

Output:

```
5219
```

---

But if I run the query without `COUNT` it returns only 10 rows. My question is,

> Why does MySQL ignore `LIMIT` when the `COUNT` is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` is for returning a subset of the total results, in your case the result is only one line so no effect

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `LIMIT` clause to select a *limited number of records* whereas `count` is aggregate function, which will return result of aggregation. It won't make any sense to use `LIMIT` and `COUNT` together as `LIMIT` may return any random n records.

Comment: `LIMIT` have never returned random rows for me, results are always returned in an order even without a primary key.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala that is the reason I said, **may**. Because, as per documentation, *MySQL uses indexes in some cases when normally it would prefer to do a full table scan*